# How to use python2.7 to write more table of sqlite3 by using loop

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a question to write different table by using loop

I have 3 table in sqlite file.

its name are Table_A, Table_B and Table_C

And i want to use loop to do it.

Could you help me to teach how to write the script.

My Code

```
import sqlite3
Data_temp= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.sqlite')

conn.execute('INSERT INTO Table_A values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', Data_temp)
conn.execute('INSERT INTO Table_B values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', Data_temp)
conn.execute('INSERT INTO Table_C values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', Data_temp)
conn.commit()
```

Thank you, erveybody!!

Comment: Can you expand on what you are trying to do? Are you trying to create the SQL statement in a loop so that you only have one execute statement?  Or are you trying to write many rows of data into each table?

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of asking myself the same thing... Why are you writing the same data to 3 different tables ?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a homework to me, but w/e.

```
tables = ["Table_A ", "Table_B", "Table_C"]
for table in tables:
    conn.execute('INSERT INTO {} values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'.format(table), Data_temp)
```

If you are using this, however, you will have to be extra-careful with the format thing. If tablenames are coming from user input, you will open your code to sql injection.